# How to use the user-accounts meteor package for two different user sign-ups?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am a bit new to meteor,I have been trying to create a login system for two different types of users say buyer and seller.When i use the useraccounts package and call the atform template {{>atform}} i can create accounts easily.But i want some added fields for the seller account registration(signup) say store name,phone no etc.,if i add those fields to atForm template they are reflected on buyer signup too,How can i get around this?is there any way to give two different looks to the atform template?

Comment: Thanks for joining the Stack Overflow Community! Please review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since you segregating type of user, you can use https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles.
2. From your question, what I understood is you navigate to `atForm` after you s ign-in. So while sign-up/registering you can provide selectbox to ask what kind of user he/she is and then just beforing creating user you can assign a role too.
3. For `atForm`, you can have a common form, but you can check `role` before showing certain fields.